# Serve a different cache file with a HTTP_REFERER condition in my .HTACCESS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-referer

If  a visit is coming from apple.com I want to serve the index2.html file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index2.html -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\.apple\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index2.html" [L]
```

If a visit is coming from another domain  just serve the default file: index.html

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html" [L]
```

***The problem is no matter if I'm coming from apple.com, the .htaccess only serves the index.html***

Comment: Is the link pointing from apple.com to your site using HTTPS?

Comment: So most likely one of all those strange conditions is not met.